# BigQuery Query Latest Table Efficiently

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to efficiently query from the *latest* table in a dataset that consists of tables of the form `project_id:dataset:dataset_20160101`, `project_id:dataset:dataset_20160102` etc.

This query seems to be the recommended solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `project_id.dataset.*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX=(SELECT MAX(table_id) FROM `project_id.dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`)
```

However, this query bills me for accessing *all* tables in the dataset, not just the latest one.  Why is that?

Comment: I am having the same issue, I think it is a bug on Google side. When I compare running the query using a hard coded value for _TABLE_SUFFIX, it is the same execution time. It seems like the same amount is being processed.

Answer (score 0):

We can only prune the tables before the query runs when the WHERE clause uses a constant expression on the pseudo column, e.g., _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'dataset_20160102'. For your query, as the WHERE clause includes a sub-uery which doesn't parse to a constant, we cannot prune the tables before the query runs. Instead, data is read from all tables and the sub-query is executed. Then data is joined with the sub-query results and filtered.

It's possible to prune the tables during the query execution. Start the query, execute the sub-query, prune the tables, and read data. But there's no ETA for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

For now, if you have a pipeline which inserts tables, then at the end of the pipeline, you could 
(1) get the MAX(table_id)
(2) create a view with following query:

```
SELECT
        *,
        DATE max_table_id AS _LATEST_DATE,
        PARSE_DATE('%E4Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS _DATA_DATE
FROM `project_id.dataset.*`
```

Then whenever you want to query the data, you could just query against the view, and specify _DATA_DATE=_LATEST_DATE as the filter. In this case, _LATEST_DATE is pre-calculated, so it's constant. As Hua explained, you will be billed for processing only the latest table.